# Getting data out of PDO associative array

Tags: php, html

I have a search page (search.php) which finds the "jokes" created by a particular author.

```
    <?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include_once($class.'.php');
});
  $obj=new oopCrud;

      if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
      extract($_REQUEST);
      $obj->search($authorid,"joke");}

}
?>
    <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="main_heading">Search Jokes</h1>
        <form action="searchform.html.php" method="post">
            <p>View jokes satisfying the following criteria:</p>
            <div>
                <label for="author">By author:</label>
                <select name="authorid" id="authorid">
            <?php foreach($obj->showData("author") as $value){
            extract($value);
            echo @<<<show
            <option value=$id>$name</option>
show;
    }
  ?>
        </select>
            </div>
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" class="btn">
            </div>
        </form>
        </div><!-- end of wrapper -->
```

In my controller file (oopCRUD.php) the jokes are located and stored in an associative array as follows:

public function search($authorid,joke){

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM joke WHERE authorid = :authorid";
$q = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':authorid'=>$authorid));
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//print_r($data); This has shown that there is the required data stored in the array.
//exit();
return $data;
```

}

I want to send this data to a searchresults.php page to display the results. How do I send or retrieve the data set on the searchresults.php page and then display it? I do not want to use jQuery / AJAX etc just straight php / html.

I am using PDO to create queries and using an Object Orientated Programming approach.

Comment: You can create one instance of oopCRUD and then use it when searching on search.php page, Just pass the search term to that instance (You are already doing this) ... Then you just need to get hat return search data in one variable and use it in the search.php -> Makes sense ?

Comment: You say to "get that return search data in one variable and use it in the search.php". Do you mean use it in the searchresults.php?  Also how would you do this? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get the Data on page refresh (submit):**

$results = $obj->search($authorid,"joke");

**Load Data**

and in your html code...

```
<select name="authorid" id="authorid">
<?php 
     if($results){ 
          foreach($results as $result){ 
               foreach($result as $key=>$val) { 
                   ?>
                       echo "<option value={$val['id']}>{$val['name']}</option>"
                   <?php
               }
          }
     }
?>
```

I am not that sure about the what you want to do with result and ->showData function. Try if this helps.

===

MultiDimensional Array to Table ... you can use `echo "<table>"` too, if you dont wont to close out php tags every time.

```
<?php

$results = array(
            array('jokeid' => 13, 'joketext' =>'Why did the chicken cross the road? To avoid getting roasted.', 'jokedate' => '2017-04-15', 'authorid' => 1 ), 
            array('jokeid' => 16, 'joketext' => 'This is test joke2', 'jokedate' => '2017-04-16', 'authorid' => 1 )
        );

if($results)
{
    ?><table><?php
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        ?><tr><?php
        foreach($result as $key=>$val)
        {
            ?><td> <?php echo $val; ?> </td> <?php
        }
        ?></tr><?php
    }
   ?> </table> <?php
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this does not work.  If I change the function to use fetchAll instead of fetch then I get a partial solution which is an associative array looking like this using print_r:

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this does not work.  If I change the function to use fetchAll instead of fetch then I get a partial solution which is an associative array looking like this using print_r:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [jokeid] => 13 [joketext] => Why did the chicken cross the road? To avoid getting roasted. [jokedate] => 2017-04-15 [authorid] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [jokeid] => 16 [joketext] => This is test joke2 [jokedate] => 2017-04-16 [authorid] => 1 ) )

How would you display this multidimensional array in a table format?

Comment: Thanks so much - this is working pretty well now with your help. One final issue - in my original question I wanted to take the result set and display it on a different page to the search page. So the data flow goes from - get the search criteria using search.php - send this to the search function inside the class oopCRUD.php which is then sent to searchresults.php for display. At the moment the way this is working is that the result data is being displayed on search.php i.e. the original search page. Do you know a way of getting the data to searchresult.php?

Comment: Errm ... I am not sure why you want search.php and searchresults.php different. Two ways though - 1. Keep only one search.php or searchresults.php. Add the search logic in searchresults.php and pass the search term there ... so your flow will be user searches something -> get search term and pass on searchresults.php in get param then just use oopCRUD to fetch results like above before loading page. 2. include search.php in your searchresults.php and just check if results not blank then load them.

Comment: I'm trying to do the second of the options you have given but every time I include searchresults.php inside the search.php it just adds the searchresults.php to the search.php page.
So Ihave this on my search.php page:
<?php
   if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
      extract($_REQUEST);
      $results = $obj->search($authorid,"joke");
 include('searchresults1.php');
?>
How do I get searchresults1.php to open on its own without being added to search.php??

Comment: Don't worry about my last comment - managed to do this successfully. Really appreciated your help.  Thanks.